# Array Filter not filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, primes

I am trying to filter an array of random numbers to pull out primes.

I have a working function (`isPrime`) that appears to return `true` or `false` correctly but every number in the array is being "filtered" into the array returned by the filter.

I looked at the documentation for filter and watched some videos but I haven't figured it out, I think it may have to do with the function call inside of the filter. Can you tell me where my error is?

```js
numArray = [];

for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
  numArray.push(Math.random(1000));
}

const isPrime = (num) => {
  for(i=2;i<num;i++){
    if(num % i === 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const results = numArray.filter(value => isPrime(value));
  
for(num in results){
  console.log(num);
  console.log(isPrime(num)) //added to demonstrate function is working and should return false to the filter                        
}
```

Comment: Math.random(1000) doesn't return integer, you have to round it.

Comment: Math.random doesn’t work like that.  All your numbers will be floats between 0 and almost 1

Comment: @ChrisLi Thank you, yes that does appear to be the reason that my program is not working but in addition it appears I fumbled checking my results as well in the last for loop by referencing the index of the number stored in numArray instead of the value as pointed out in the accepted answer

Comment: @James the above

Comment: @VLAZ the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating random number in wrong way. Your code will only create an array of floating points less than `1` so according to your `isPrime` they all will be prime.

**Note:** Don't use variables without `let` or `cosnt` it can cause many problems in the code.

#### How to create random numbers?

- `Math.random()` is function which returns a floating point number between `0` and `1`.
- You multiply that number with the max range you want to have.
- After multiplying it will still be a floating number. So use `Math.floor()` to round the random float to an integer

```js
let numArray = [];

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
  numArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 30));
}

const isPrime = (num) => {
  for(let i=2;i<num;i++){
    if(num % i === 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const results = numArray.filter(value => isPrime(value));

console.log(JSON.stringify(numArray))
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Answering OP's question that

> "Why bottom for loop used to check the code gives numbers  5, 6 ... 997, 998"

In javascript arrays are basically objects. The `for..in` is a loop which iterates over the **keys** of the object not the values. So in case arrays keys are the indexes of the array which are `0...999` in above case. So it was logging those indexes

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!

Do you know why the bottom for loop that I was using to check the program shows the numbers as 5, 6 ... 997, 998 etc then if they were numbers less than one, and the isPrime function was working as intended in the bottom loop as well?

Comment: @DeSync Updated the post for explanation of that. If you want anything else feel free to ask?

Comment: Ohh ok, no thats all thanks so much for the help!